# divide one row record into 2 rows in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my Sql table, I want to divide a row record into 2 rows.
sample data set given below.

[image]

Need to divide 2 rows like this.

[image]

This is the query I used

```
SELECT FRCS2.[CID],FRCS2.[DATE],FRCS2.[Status], 
                    FRCS1.[ID],FRCS1.[DATE],FRCS1.[Status]
FROM #temp FRCS1
INNER JOIN #temp FRCS2
ON FRCS1.[ID] = FRCS2.[ID]
```

Please help me to solve this.
Thanks.

Comment: Show us how you're getting the above dataset, as you have 2 sets of columns with the same name, and a defined object can't have 2 columns with the same name.

Comment: UNION ALL comes to mind.

Comment: That `JOIN` looks incomplete. The jJOIN you show would mean that the second set of columns would have the same value as the first, not different, as you're selecting from the same table and joining on the same `ID` (and I *assume* the ID is unique).

Comment: @Larnu If this was a real question with a real table, `UNPIVOT` or `CROSS APPLY + VALUES` would have been the answer.

Comment: I would personally use `CROSS APPLY` and a `VALUES` table construct, @Charlieface , but on the face of it, what the OP has doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, I would recommend `apply`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (id1, date1, status1), (id2, date2, status2)
     ) v(id, date, status);
```

Note that column names cannot be duplicated in a table.  So, this assumes that the columns actually have different names.

This approach is preferred over `union all` because it only scans the table once.  For a small table, the performance difference is negligible.  It is noticeable for larger tables and can be quite significant if the "table" is really a subquery, CTE, or view.

Answer (score 0):

You want `UNION ALL` here:

```sql
SELECT ID1, DATE1, STATUS1 FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT ID2, DATE2, STATUS;
```

Note that I assume that your actual columns don't have the same names, because they can't.